# Proof and Demonstration

Tags: logic

I started a mathematical logic course this term, and as I understood the first order language can be seen as a tool to do mathematics in a rigorous way. For instance mathematical logic gives us a precise definition of what a proof is, i.e. how to build sequences from others. So, if I start with the group axioms I could use first order language to conclude certain formulas. However, I was wondering when we are proving things about the language itself, for instance transitivity of $\vDash$, can these proofs be regarded more as "intuitive proofs/demonstrations" or can they actually be done by using the formal definition of the proof, i.e using sequences.

Comment: Formally proved using definition of $\vdash$.

Comment: Thank you Mauro, maybe my example was not that good. Let's take the proposition: If t is a term then it cannot be the empty word. As I understand it we need an axiom system to follow something, does first order logic have one? sorry I am fairly new to this topic

Comment: The syntax of the language has rules. A term is either a variable (see list in the syntactical specs) or a constant (see list) or...

Comment: I'm not completely sure whether I understand precisely what you are asking. However, of course, as you noted, there is a difference between a formal derivation 'in' a logic and a (meta-theoretical) proof 'about' some logic in question. Perhaps sometimes this is not payed much attention to, but, depending on your interests/goals/intentions, the difference is crucial. Usually, according to that difference, people speak of the theory (logic, language) - level on one hand, and (so-called) $meta$-theory ($meta$-logic, $meta$-language) - level on the other hand.

Comment: The interplay between those levels may be a matter of various subjects, in any case, as far as I understand, of reductive proof theory (in a narrower, more technical sense) and also generally of the philosophy of mathematics and logic (in a broader sense).